# WordPress - How can I target the most recent post and modify it?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm working on a shortcode and I'd like to target the most recent "Event". Targeting this most recent "Event" I'd like to do two things.

1. Being able to apply a specific class to it so I can style it differently (I don't want to use `first-child`).
2. Add `the_excerpt()` to it.

Currently the shortcode pulls the most recent 4 "Events". So the most recent would need what I mentioned above. I'd imagine it would have to do something with "count" but I'm not entirely sure, still trying to learn this stuff.

```
add_shortcode( 'show_events', 'events_query' );

function events_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'category_name' => 'events',
    );
    $events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
        $html_out = '<article>';
        while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
            $events_query->the_post();
            // Do stuff with each post here
            $html_out .= '<div class="events-item"><div class="meta-date">' . Date('F j, Y') . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4></div>/div></div>';
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = 'No Events Found.';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated using code from an answer:

```
add_shortcode( 'show_events', 'events_query' );

function events_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'category_name' => 'events',
    );
    $events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
        $html_out = '<article>';
        $counter = 0;
        $event_class = 'events-item';
        while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
            if ( $counter == 0 ) {
                 $event_class = 'events-item most-recent';
            }
            $events_query->the_post();
            // Do stuff with each post here
            $html_out .= '<div class="' . $event_class . '"><div class="meta-date">' . Date('F j, Y') . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h5><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h5></div></div>';

            if ( $counter == 0 ) {
                $html_out .= '<div class="meta-info">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
            }
            $html_out .= '</div>';
            $counter++;
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = 'No Events Found.';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Darren it's me again :)
You can use additional var `$counter` to check if it's the first post
Here is the code

```
add_shortcode( 'show_events', 'events_query' );

function events_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'category_name' => 'events',
    );
    $events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
        $html_out = '<article>';
        $counter = 0;

        while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
            $event_class = 'events-item';
            if ( $counter == 0 ) {
                 $event_class = 'events-item first-event, additiona-classes';
            }
            $events_query->the_post();
            // Do stuff with each post here
            $html_out .= '<div class="' . $event_class . '"><div class="meta-date">' . Date('F j, Y') . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4></div>/div>';

            if ( $counter == 0 ) {
                $html_out .= '<div class="meta-info">' . $post->post_excerpt . '</div>';
            }
            $html_out .= '</div>';
            $counter++;
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = 'No Events Found.';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver. I feel like this is close though. I'm getting an "undefined variable" on `$post->post_excerpt`. Is this the same as `the_excerpt()`?

Comment: Hmm, I think that the post excerpt is empty. Would it be possible to check if the post has excerpt in excerpt field? Please refer to the following [link](http://www.mhthemes.com/support/custom-excerpts-wordpress/).

Comment: Stanimir, I've updated my OP. I swapped `$post->post_excerpt` for `get_the_excerpt()` and I didn't get any errors anymore. The only issue is all of my posts are getting `class="most-recent` when it should only be the first. Here's a demo [link](http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/rawafid/).

Comment: I have updated the code above. The problem was that the event_class is created outside the while and it changes when the first posts id displayed. The it stays the same for all other posts. I move it inside the while and it works for me. Please try the code above and let us know if you still have problems.

Comment: Bingo. You sir, are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dear please use the if codition

```
add_shortcode( 'show_events', 'events_query' );

function events_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'category_name' => 'events',
    );
    $events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
        $html_out = '<article>';
        $i=1;
        while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
            $events_query->the_post();
            if($i==1){
             $class = "new_class";
             $excerpt = the_excerpt(); 
             }
            $html_out .= '<div class="events-item'.$class."><div class="meta-date">' . Date('F j, Y') . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>
            <p>'.$excerpt.'</p></div></div></div>';
            $i++;
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = 'No Events Found.';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```